# Multiprocessing: escaping join()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm performing parallel operations on a set of files, the basic function is:

```
def funcOnFile(fileName):
    print('Executing ', fileName)
    readFile
    ....
    saveOutputFile
```

Since each file is independent from the others, I can easily do this in parallel without having threads talking to each others.
However I must be sure to keep at least one core free at all the time otherwise my old computer will freeze and die

What I do is then:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

for i in range(0, len(filenames), numProcesses):
       processes = []
       for j in range(numProcesses):
           index = i + j
           if index >= len(filenames):
               break

           filename = filenames[index]
           process = multiprocessing.Process(
               name=os.path.basename(filename),
               target=func, args=(filename, args)
           )
           processes.append(process)
           process.start()

       for p in processes:
           p.join()
```

at the end of this process I want to sync the files to my s3 remote repository, and I do it using `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.run(['aws', 's3', 'sync', localOuputs, s3Output])
```

However, it happens that the sync starts before the last files are saved!
Does anyone has an explanation/fix for this? I thought that this would be avoided by the `join()`

Comment: "I must be sure to keep at least one core free at all the time otherwise my old computer will freeze and die." Do you have a bad core or something?

Comment: Suggest to use `joblib` package for multiprocessing which is easy to use.

Comment: Instead of `join()`, try using something like `all([not p.is_alive() for p in processes])` to determine when they've all finished.

Comment: What do you mean by "the sync starts before the last files are saved"? Are the files missing or incomplete? Have you checked the actually processing did not fail? Check the processes exit code after joining them.